# cannot connect using sql developer

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, tns

cannot connect using sql developer.

I use the same username and password in sqlPlus and it would allow me to connect, however :when I 
try Sql Developer I get

Status: Failure - Test failed: Listener refused the connection with the following error: ORA-12505
TNS:listenner dows not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor.

my oracle version win32_11gR2_database_1of2
my computer window 8.

I have also tried install it on XP, Vista, and Windows7 and have gotten  the same error.
I have also gotten error when I am install oracle, the first error is say that all the computers
do meet the minimum standard, I continue with the install.  when I try to use Sql Developer it 
ask for the Java.exe
**C:\app12\Database\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\jdk\bin**
and click ok

Comment: Make sure you are trying to connect to the correct database with a correct sid. (sid - Mostly it will be xe/XE )

Answer (score 0):

You may not have the correct TNSNAMES directory setup in SQL Developer.  Try going to:

Tools -> Preferences -> Database -> Advanced

[image: SQL Developer Preferences]

You can setup the correct TNSNames directory here.